# Why does regex only match a string when others are present?

Tags: java, regex

I have a white list of HTML end tags (`br`, `b`, `i`, `div`):-

```
String whitelist = "([^br|^b|^i|^div])";
String endTagPattern = "(<[ ]*/[ ]*)" + whitelist + "(>?).*?([^>]+>)";
...
html = html.replaceAll(endTagPattern, "[r]");
```

Which takes my test `String` and removes the end tags of those not in the white list, in this case replaced by `[r]` for clarity:-

```
1. <b>bold</b>, 2. <i>italic</i>, 3. <strong>strong</strong>, 4. <div>div</div>, 5. <script lang='test'>script</script>
1. <b>bold</b>, 2. <i>italic</i>, 3. <strong>strong[r], 4. <div>div</div>, 5. <script lang='test'>script[r]
```

If I add `strong` to this white list

```
String whitelist = "([^br|^b|^i|^div|^strong])";
```

Not only does it not match the `strong` end tag, it also stops matching that of the end `script` tag or any other for that matter.

My question is, why?

Comment: [This answer might be pertinent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2071828). You have also not understood how regex works - the pattern `[^br|^b|^i|^div|^strong]` is a character group that matches **not** `b` or `r` or `|` or `d` or `i` etc...

Comment: I realise that parsing HTML in any complex way is painful if not impossible but it should be possible to remove tags here and there no?

Comment: (1) using HTML and regex is really bad idea. You should use parser instead. (2) It seems you are confusing [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(...)` and [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[...]`.

Comment: The point is that no, it is not possible. Because tags can feature in all sorts of places - in attribute values for example. Regex is simply to capable of breaking down full HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String whitelist = "([^br|^b|^i|^div])";
```

Using `[]` creates a character class. I presume you wrote this so you could use `^` for "not", but a character class is inappropriate here. Inside square brackets, `|` does not mean "or"; it's just a literal pipe character. And writing `div` doesn't match the *word* `div`, it matches one of the three characters, `d`, `i`, or `v`. Negating that means "match anything except `d`, `i`, or `v`.

That whitelist is effectively equivalent to `[^bdirv|\^]` — it matches a single character that is not `b`, `d`, `i`, `r`, `v`, `|`, or `^`.

```
String whitelist = "(?!br|b|i|div)";
```

If you want to exclude certain matches, what you want is [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Leaving out the square brackets lets you use `|` the way you intended, as an "or" operator.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that you are using a character class. Inside a character class, the order of characters does not really matter except if you're dealing with character ranges.

So, `[^br|^b|^i|^div|^strong]` actually will match any character except those:

```
bridvstrong|^
```

[Note that `|` and `^` are there too].

You could have used `[^bridvstrong|^]` and it would behave the same way.

You might instead look into negative lookaheads.

Comment: Ah phooey, thought I'd get around doing some importing with some simple regex.  I was wrong, I've learned my lesson.  No more HTML and Regexing for me.